# MySQL trigger to multiply value

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger that will multiply the sales_price field by -1, the sales table is like this transaction type, it has varchar R for refund and S for Sales.

This is the trigger I am trying to create:

```
delimiter $$     
CREATE trigger refund_negative before insert on sale 
for each row    
begin
set new.SALE_PRICE = new.SALE_PRICE *(-1)   
where TRA_TYPE = 'R';
end;   
delimiter $$
```

Comment: what do you want to happen?

Comment: I need the trigger to change the int value to a negative where the transaction type is = R , so for instance when i put a new row in the table i put 10.99 as sale price and R or S as transaction type, but need to change the value 10.99 to -10.99 every time transaction type is R

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `refund_negative` BEFORE INSERT ON `sales` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF NEW.TRA_TYPE='R' THEN
    SET NEW.price = NEW.price * -1;
END IF;
END
```

so basically it just test whether `TRA_TYPE` is equal to 'R' and if so, `NEW.price` is multiplied by negative one.

Comment: This is super !! Thanks a million !! 5 star to you ! i could not figure out what i was doing  wrong. thanks a million for your help!!

Comment: i do not know why it is not taking my positive vote for you!! anyway thanks a million Good Job